# Tools for creating old-fashioned maps

Tags: software-recommendations, basemap, design

Are you aware of any software/tools which permit the automatized or semi-automatized creation of old-fashioned maps based on data one owns?

I love the design of old-fashioned maps, in particular the symbols used for buildings, mountains and forests. They transfer a lot of visual information, with often limited use of colour.

A related possibility is the Stamen Watercolor style for basemaps, which looks very nice, but does not visualize a lot of information.

Here are some examples:
http://cdn.supadupa.me/shop/14281/images/1165979/switzerland_1721_p2_grande.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/47/be/c9/47bec90a7c79c3cfeaef6cb6c413914a.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymlJp.jpg

Comment: do you have an example (i.e. image) of such "old fashioned" map ?

Comment: A simple internet search with "old style map" or "vintage map" return lot of exemple/tutorial/how to for either QGIS or ESRI product (ArcMap, ArcPro). I suggest you look at these and come back with more focus question

Comment: [softwarerecs.se] is the SE place for software recommendations.  GIS SE uses a Focused question/Best Answer model, and tries to steer away from lists or opinions.

Comment: @radouxju I've added some examples, I hope it illustrates the question better!

Comment: @J.R true, I must have used the wrong keywords. I think the key difference here is that I am looking for automatic tools, not a design solution like Photoshop (as often proposed in search results)

Comment: @Vince thank you, I wasn't aware of this SE site

Answer (score 1):

[Thunderforest](https://www.thunderforest.com/maps/) make a nice "olden days" themed map called Pioneer.